# Code wont return a error trying to find a user , even when the user does not exist in the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm using javascript and parse.com

The below section of code should query the parse.com back end and look for users that exist called "Rob". When inspecting it using Chrome dev tools no errors are returned to the console.

However the code always completes successfully, even using the example shown where I know that there is not a user called "Rob" stored in that parse object.

I dont understand what I'm missing in my code or why it wont error if the user does not exist?

```
var friendFinder = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", "Rob");  // find users that match
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
   console.log("Yay");
  },
error: function (contact, error) {
 //Show if no user was found to match

 alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }

})
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not finding a row is not an error condition.  The result of the call was successful, and your results were empty.

Comment: To clarify: an "error" in this context means it couldn't connect, or the search wasn't run, or the search failed to return anything. Successfully returning an empty set is not considered an error.

Comment: @Bill Greg Thanks, I'm happy with the answer, could you just tell me how I could visualize that no result was returned? or is that out of scope of the original question?

Comment: I would just inspect "results" in dev tools.  You should see it has an empty array in it.

Comment: if (results.length) { // yay }